# How to make equal size of Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a `asp.net` (`C#`) project Where I am using `gridview` to show details. But My all of the cells are not of same size. Please Help me to make them of equal size.

[image]

`aspx` design code of `Gridview` :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333300" 
                                onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" 
                                HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="5">
                                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="True" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Enrollment" HeaderText="Enrollment" 
                                        SortExpression="Enrollment" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject" 
                                        SortExpression="Subject" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message" 
                                        SortExpression="Message" />
                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                <HeaderStyle BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Inset" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                    VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                <EditRowStyle BorderStyle="Solid" />
                            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Post your Aspx design code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the column width or you can use ***css*** for this or you have one more option using ***SQL*** just write query like this:

```
SELECT Enrollment, Subject, SUBSTRING(Message, 0, 35) AS Message
FROM tblInfo
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give a 100% width for your grid view.Because you have provide an image with a grid view which has the width of whole page.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="dtgGrid" runat="server"  Width="100%" >
```

Then you can give same widths for your columns as percentages As below.
Code may be changed according to your design. But the method as follows.

```
<HeaderStyle Width="33%"  />
```

Your Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333300" 
                            onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" 
                            HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="5" Width="100%">
                            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="True" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Enrollment" HeaderText="Enrollment" 
                                    SortExpression="Enrollment" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject" 
                                    SortExpression="Subject" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message" 
                                    SortExpression="Message" />
                            </Columns>
                            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Inset" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="33%" />
                            <EditRowStyle BorderStyle="Solid" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: @Shrawan if not working that is means that you have some text inside that can not split, or you use no breaking space and not simple spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add RowStyle

```
 <RowStyle Width="300px"/>
```

**(Or)**

1.Add the CSS in the header.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .maxWidthGrid
    {
        max-width: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

2.Then use the CSS in necessary columns like this ItemStyle-CssClass="maxWidthGrid"

```
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="maxWidthGrid" DataField="ClientName" HeaderText="Client Name"
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ClientName" />
```

**(Or)**

To fix the column’s width, we should break the text in cells. The following code is for your reference.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TableCell myCell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            myCell.Style.Add("word-break", "break-all");
            myCell.Width = 300;
        }
    }
```